# Android Interfaces implementation

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with interfaces, i have a class that implements an interface which i expect to fire after a network response of 200. My interface is not called (how do i hook it to my NetworkrequestClass?)

```
//My class
  public class MyClass extends AnotherClass implements MyDesiredListener{

    private void myMethod(){

       if (!value) {
         NetworkCallClass.specificRequest(); //To call onDesiredLoadedData 
        }
     }

    @Override
    onDesiredLoadedData(){
      //Update Value
     }
   }

   //My inteface in its own file
   interface  MyDesiredListener{
   onDesiredLoadedData();
   }
```

Comment: Ok...I deleted my earlier comment. I wanted to ask where will you know you are receiving valid data (i.e. your `NetworkCallClass.specificRequest();` will complete)..?

Comment: Thats the question, how can I hook the result in `NetworkCallclass.specificRequest` so that the interface is called when there are results? 
`specificRequest` runs on a separate thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if I did here you are:

```
public class FirstClass implements MyInterface {
    public void method() {
        NetworkCallClass clazz = new NetworkCallClass(this);
        clazz.specificRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDesiredLoadedData() {
        // here you are your callback
    }
}

public class NetworkCallClass {
    MyInterface _callbacks;

    public NetworkCallClass(MyInterface callbacks) {
        _callbacks = callbacks;
    }

    public void specificRequest() {
        // code
        if (networkResponse == 200) {
            _callbacks.onDesiredLoadedData();
        }
    }
}
```